# OCaml verbose type error

Tags: types, compiler-errors, ocaml

Is it possible to have OCaml show more detail on type error. For example

```
Error: This expression has type AAAAA
       but an expression was expected of type BBBBB
```

There are times when I waste a lot of energy trying to figure out which obscure statements expect BBBBB causing such error. It would be nice if it can display the problematic lines.

Comment: Without a bit of code showing where you think the compiler is not doing a good job, this is just a rant and not a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. But you need a bit of collaboration with a compiler, and then it will respond to you in a more friendly error. So the answer to your question is - use type annotations. When you annotate expressions, you give a compiler more information on your intentions. And then compiler can show you the error that is much closer to the actual point of failure.

Example:

You have right a function, that typechecks, but contains a bug:

```
let run sum n lst = 
    List.fold ~init:(sum,n)
              ~f:(fun (s,n) x -> s + x, n + 1)
```

later, you're trying to use it and it spills a strange error on you:

```
let average lst =
    let (sum,n) = run 0 0 lst in
    sum / n;;
    Characters 36-47:
      let (sum,n) = run 0 0 lst in
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^
Error: This expression has type int Core_kernel.Std.List.t -> int * int
       but an expression was expected of type 'a * 'b
```

So, you're in trouble, and you need to investigate the problem. You start to add annotations, essentially explaining to a compiler your intentions. Some time after, you will return to your definition of `run` and add an annotation:

```
let run sum n lst : int * int = 
    List.fold ~init:(sum,n)
              ~f:(fun (s,n) x -> s + x, n + 1)
```

And find out that the actual error is inside this function.

So, there're some rules, that will help you to get a much more informative errors from compiler:

1. Annotate top-level expressions (you can omit some details, if don't like to specify them, so that the code is still readable. For example, instead of `(very * complex types) list`, you can write `'a list`, or `('a, 'b types) list`. Note, here `'a` and `'b` don't stand for polymorphic type variables, this is just a way to say to compiler: "Oh, I really don't know, or don't care what they stand for, just feel free to fill it with whatever you want", or in other words, you're not constraining a type-checker on this types).
2. Always annotate wildcards. If you have something like this:

   let _ = List.fold ...

Then make sure that this wildcards stands actually for what you're thinking of them:

```
let _ : int option = List.fold ...
```

3. Use `merlin`. It will allow you to catch errors in the moment you've created them, not several hours later.

Last words: the OCaml typechecker is just a constraint solver, and if you give it a detailed sets of constraints it will give you back a detailed answer. Otherwise, for bad input it will give you a bad output.

Comment: yes, your approach is the best practice and can resolve my problem, although I was on the impression that the compiler must have some in-depth information of how types are conflict, why can't it just display them. In my particular case, it usually happens when refactoring function. If a function is called from many places, and also passed as a parameter to other functions. I cannot just search the name of the function, because it could be renamed to something else inside other functions. Also never heard of merlin before, I will look into it.

Comment: compiler has a set of constraints, like `expr` should have type `x`, in a process of type checking he adds new constraints to the set, until it hits two constraints that contradicts each other. This is a type error and compiler just outputs them. Compiler even does not know what constraint was the first, and what was added later. It could possibly expose other constraints, but it would work only for very small programs. On a large scale it will create more confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Arthur Charguéraud has written a patch for the OCaml compiler that provides easier to understand error messages. It is described in [this article](https://ocaml.org/meetings/ocaml/2014/ocaml2014_9.pdf) from the 2014 ML Workshop and the corresponding code is [on github](https://github.com/charguer/ocaml). To quote an example provided in the presentation, if you type

```
let rev_filter f l =
  List.fold_left (fun x acc -> if f x then x::acc else acc) [] [1; 2; 3]
```

instead of having the classical error message

```
Error: This expression has type 'a list
       but an expression was expected of type 'a.
       The type variable 'a occurs inside 'a list
```

which admittedly is not very helpful, you have this new one:

```
Error: The function `List.fold_left' expects 3 arguments of types
       ['a -> 'b -> 'a] and ['a] and ['b list],
       but it is given 3 arguments of types ['c -> 'c list -> 'c list]
       and ['d list] and [int list].
```

which let you compare the expected and actual types of the arguments and hopefully understand that you have to swap `x` and `acc` in `fun x acc ->`

Comment: this will be useful indeed

Comment: @nlucaroni the spoiler `>!` was there on purpose: as the question is about understanding error messages, I'd argue that it's better to let readers search by themselves where the issue lies and whether the second message is more helpful than the first one for this purpose.

Comment: Why did this patch never get merged into the core? :-(  It's now out of date and unusable.